# facebook api: event url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

lets say I know I have an event ID. I would like the event URL (to link users to it), but the graph API does not seem to have it (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/), for example if I use the command `GET /v2.9/310917539364835 HTTP/1.1` the output is:

```
{
  "description": "...",
  "end_time": "2017-06-23T22:30:00+1000",
  "name": "UQ Postgrad Masquerade Party (End of Semester)",
  "place": {
    "name": "Cloudland",
    "location": {
      "city": "Brisbane",
      "country": "Australia",
      "latitude": -27.45891,
      "longitude": 153.0349699,
      "state": "QLD",
      "street": "641 Ann Street",
      "zip": "4006"
    },
    "id": "103221159774910"
  },
  "start_time": "2017-06-23T19:30:00+1000",
  "id": "310917539364835"
}
```

but there is not URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after doing some searching, it turns out that the URL is:
facebook.com/ + ID
so in this example. facebook.com/310917539364835

Comment: Exactly the answer I needed.  Bonus points for Cloudland in the valley haha.